# Update Query Using Select Query in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to add 4 columns in all the tables of ms access (which i will import), and then update them on the basis of my select query result. However my update query is not working. Can anyone please have a look and let me know the solution

Thanks

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim objtbl As DAO.TableDef
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sq2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sq3 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sq4 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sq5 As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each objtbl In db.TableDefs
    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & " ADD COLUMN     [Account] Text;"
  db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & " ADD COLUMN [Account_Serial] Text;"
  db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & " ADD COLUMN [Invoice_Date] Text;"
  db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & "ADD Column [LOB] Text;"
  db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & "ADD Column [LOB] Text;"
  q = "Select [Field3] from " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & " Where " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Field1] = ""CUSTOMERRECORD"";"
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [Field3] from " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & " Where " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Field1] = ""CUSTOMERRECORD"";")
  Set sq2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Field4 from " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & "Where" & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Field1] = ""CUSTOMERRECORD"";")
  Set sq3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Field5 from" & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & "Where" & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Field1] = ""Customerrecord"";")
  Set sq4 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Field6 from" & "[" & objtbl.Name & "]" & "Where" & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Field1] = ""Customerrecord"";")
  db.Execute
  db.Execute "Update " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "] SET " & "[" & objtbl.Name & "].[Account] = " & rs!Field3 & ";"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Access may not be immediately reflecting the changes you made to the table, unless you refresh the database window.

Try adding the command **Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow** after you alter the tables and before you open the recordsets.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code. Then fix all errors that you will get. E.g.

- missing space before ADD: `& "ADD Column [LOB] Text;"`
- adding [LOB] twice
- missing space after FROM: `("Select Field5 from" & "[" &`
- you open sq2..4 but don't do anything with them
- `db.Execute` without parameters

Defining a variable `sTable = "[" & objtbl.Name & "]"` and using that everywhere would make your code much better readable.

If Field3 is a text field, you probably need

```
" .[Account] = '" & rs!Field3 & "';"
```

Comment: Thanks Andre.. Your last point did the trick. i will make further changes suggested by you.